# How to modify data after waiting for it to be fetched react axios

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to get data from my API then modifying it,
I tried this:

```js
const [reports, setReports] = useState([]);
const [workers, setWorkers] = useState([]);
const [newReports, setNewReports] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    await get_user_data().then((dataRes) => {
      axios
        .get('/api/reports/?my_business=' + dataRes.id)
        .then((dataRes) => {
          setReports(dataRes.data);
          return dataRes.data[0].my_business;
        })
        .then((dataRes) => {
          axios
            .get('/api/workers/?my_business=' + dataRes)
            .then((dataRes) => {
              setWorkers(dataRes.data);
            })
            .then(() => {
              setNewReports(fix_data());
            });
        });
    });
  })();
}, []);
```

I got the **reports** and the **workers**, but when I set **newReports** I only get them in the first render, if I refresh I lose the data in new reports, that's because **setNewReports(fix_data())** don't wait for the **reports** and the **workers** to be fetched.

Here's my `fix_data()` function:

```js
function fix_data() {
  let w = {};
  let r = {};
  let rep = [];

  reports.forEach((report) => (w[report.worker_id] = workers.find((worker) => worker.id === report.worker_id)));
  reports.forEach(
    (report) => (
      (r = report), (r.worker_id = w[report.worker_id].first_name + ' ' + w[report.worker_id].last_name), rep.push(r)
    ),
  );
  return rep;
}
```

What's wrong with my useEffect function? I do call setNewReports(fix_data()) inside **then** so why it doesn't wait for the data to be fetched?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [reports, setReports] = useState([]);
const [workers, setWorkers] = useState([]);
const [newReports, setNewReports] = useState([])

const get_reports = async (dataRes) =>{
   const Report_Res = await axios.get('/api/reports/?my_business=' + dataRes.id)
   setReports(Res.data); 
} 

const get_worker_data = async (dataRes)=>{
   const Worker_Res = await axios.get('/api/workers/?my_business=' + dataRes)
   setWorkers(dataRes.data);
}

useEffect(()=>{
  get_user_data()
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
  get_reports(dataRes)
  get_worker_data(dataRes)
},[dataRes])

useEffect(()=>{
  setNewReports(fix_data())
},[reports, workers])
```

@alaa yahia It's better if you practice clean code. :)

1.Try to wrap up your each api call in separate function. It looks cleaner and easy to understand.

2. Call the functions in useEffect. Look at the 1st useEffect. they will populate the states of user Data. 2nd useEffect fetches the worker and report data which depends on DataRes. So add DataRes in dependency array of 2nd useEffect.
3. call the setNewReports(fix_data()) in 3nd useEffect. and it will make sure It fixes the data when reports and workers data are present. Look at the dependency array- [reports, workers] at the end of 3rd useeffect. That means This useEffect will run, when these [reports, workers] changes.

N.B- I wrote those codes without running. Forgive if any Typing mistake presents.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed the code a little and it worked, I didn't know how to write such a clean code with useEffect before! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that worked after small fixes on @black lotus's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66858537/2873538):

```
const [reports, setReports] = useState([]);
const [workers, setWorkers] = useState([]);
const [newReports, setNewReports] = useState([]);
const [dataRes, setDataRes]= useState([]);

const get_reports = async (dataRes) =>{
const Report_Res = await axios.get('/api/reports/?my_business=' + dataRes)
setReports(Report_Res.data);
}

const get_worker_data = async (dataRes)=>{
   const Worker_Res = await axios.get('/api/workers/?my_business=' + dataRes)
   setWorkers(Worker_Res.data);
}
const get_user = async (dataRes)=>{
   const user_Res = await get_user_data()
   setDataRes(user_Res);
}

useEffect(()=>{
  get_user()
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
  get_worker_data(dataRes)
  get_reports(dataRes)

},[dataRes])

useEffect(()=>{
  setNewReports(fix_data())
},[reports, workers])
```